# Generate doc file in ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, .doc

I need to generate doc file in `ionic` but there is no such plugin available.
Is it possible to generate doc file in `cordova` app?
I have searched for that but only found file opener `plugin`.
I am using `jspdf` to generate `Pdf` but client wants to edit that report. 
Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

I searched and there is no such plugin available currenly.

Edit:
Thank you @Abhishek Tomar for the comment. Awesome. Please try [docx](https://docx.js.org/#/?id=welcome).

Comment: Did you tried this one https://docx.js.org/#/?id=welcome ?